# transition_time is working but transition_reveal is not working (showing error)

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to animate some plots in `R` using `ggplot2` and `gganimate`.

I read some tutorials and successfully animated the `gapminder` data.

However, I have problems when I try to animate my dataset. First I created the `plot` and try to animate it like this:

```
animate_data_1 <- ggplot(data_1, 
                         aes(x = Month, y = rain, colour = factor(Year))) +
                  geom_line(stat = "identity") +
                  labs(x = "Month", y = "Rain") +
                  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 0.7) +
                  scale_color_viridis_d() 
animate_data_1

animate_data_1 + transition_time(Year) + labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}")
```

The above code is creating the animated plot, but it is showing one year at a time and then changing to another year. But, I want all year will change the value at a time (increasing from start to end). Like this example [data gradually appear](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/gganimate-how-to-create-plots-with-beautiful-animation-in-r/)

So, I made this change:

```
   animate_data_1 + 
   geom_point(aes(group = seq_along(Month))) +
   transition_reveal(Year) +
   labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}")
```

Now it showing this error:

`Error: Provided file does not exist In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`

What is the problem? How can solve this?

My data:

```
tem Month Year      rain
1  16.9760     1 1901  18.53560
2  19.9026     2 1901  16.25480
3  24.3158     3 1901  70.79810
4  28.1834     4 1901  66.16160
5  27.8892     5 1901 267.21500
6  28.8925     6 1901 341.04200
7  28.3327     7 1901 540.90700
8  27.9243     8 1901 493.21000
9  27.6057     9 1901 291.54900
10 27.0887    10 1901 199.17100
11 22.1671    11 1901 126.28500
12 18.5574    12 1901   1.69035
13 18.5455     1 1902   1.29152
14 20.1252     2 1902   0.14722
15 25.5508     3 1902  62.76860
16 26.5562     4 1902 229.58900
17 27.3165     5 1902 302.19700
18 28.2660     6 1902 528.77500
19 27.6247     7 1902 415.25700
20 28.1001     8 1902 435.16600
21 27.7271     9 1902 282.87200
22 26.0153    10 1902  76.65180
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this but the time frame in not coming. Howver, this code in not giving the gradual increasing plot but it is giving all year one after another

```
animate_data_1 + 
geom_point(aes(group = seq_along(Year)))+
transition_reveal(Year)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a movement for each month, you need to define a new variable to combine year and month as shown below, and then reveal it via `transition_time`.  You can change `fps` value to increase or decrease the speed.

```
data_1$Yearm <- data_1$Year + data_1$Month*0.08

p <- animate_data_1 + transition_time(Yearm) +
    labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}")
  animate(p, fps=5)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for your code, but this is not my expected ouput